# How to use ParallelTable and Eigensystem in right way?

Tags: list-manipulation, calculus-and-analysis, matrix, parallelization, eigenvalues

I have the next matrices:

```
EE[3] = {{1, 2}, {3, 5}}; BB[3] = {{1, 3}, {3, 3}};
EE[5] = {{1, 3}, {3, 3}}; BB[5] = {{1, 7}, {7, 3}};
EE[10] = {{5, 2}, {3, 7}}; BB[10] = {{1, 5}, {5, 3}};
```

I would like to find eigenvectors and eigenvalues:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
EE[3] = {{1, 2}, {3, 5}}; BB[3] = {{1, 3}, {3, 3}};
EE[5] = {{1, 3}, {3, 3}}; BB[5] = {{1, 7}, {7, 3}};
EE[10] = {{5, 2}, {3, 7}}; BB[10] = {{1, 5}, {5, 3}};
{eval, evec} = 
 ParallelTable[Eigensystem[{EE[i], BB[i]}], {i, {3, 5, 10}}]
```

The last raw is written incorrect. I wanted to somehow associate each pair of eigenvectors and values {eval, evec} with some kind of index so that I could easily return the right pair. How can I do that?( something like this {eval, evec}[i] or similar form).

Comment: @Henrik Schumacher, that's not what I meant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a [shared function](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetSharedFunction.html) and evaluate the [`Set`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Set.html) command on each kernel:

```
EE[3] = {{1, 2}, {3, 5}}; BB[3] = {{1, 3}, {3, 3}};
EE[5] = {{1, 3}, {3, 3}}; BB[5] = {{1, 7}, {7, 3}};
EE[10] = {{5, 2}, {3, 7}}; BB[10] = {{1, 5}, {5, 3}};

SetSharedFunction[esys];
ParallelDo[esys[i] = Eigensystem[{EE[i], BB[i]}], {i, {3, 5, 10}}]
```

Now you can define

```
esys[_] = {Missing[], Missing[]};
eval[i_] := esys[i][[1]]
evec[i_] := esys[i][[2]]
```

to access them easily with `eval[3]`, `esys[3]`, etc.

By the way you can auto-extract the list of available indices of `EE` and `BB` with

```
indices = Intersection[DownValues[EE] /. (_[EE[n_]] :> _) -> n,
                       DownValues[BB] /. (_[BB[n_]] :> _) -> n]
(*    {3, 5, 10}    *)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer!